# Alternate Slide/Un-slide of Images

Tags: jquery, slide

Could someone help me with this issue. I want to make each image to show alternate, but this time only 2 images are showing. My sample code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jay_10x/kz4525zk/26/).

Thanks for the help in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var count = -1;

  function slideImg() {
    var imgs = $('.img');
    var imgLength = imgs.length - 1;

    count < imgLength ? count++ : count = 0;
    imgs.addClass('slide').eq(count).removeClass('slide');
  }

  setInterval(slideImg, 5000);

});
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide {
  right: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: 2s !important;
  transition: 2s !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=10" />
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=23" />
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=4" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Issue:**

All three images are sliding properly, it's just that your first `<img>` is always covered by one of the other two.

You're adding the class `slide` to all images, and then removing it from one. That means at any time, two of your images will have the class `slide`. The one that's later in the DOM will always appear above.

---

**Solution 1:** *(Background-image remains in place)*

Force the "upcoming" image to appear above by giving it a higher `z-index`.

```
//This would go *before* incrementing/resetting the count
imgs.css("z-index","").eq(count).css("z-index","2");
```

**Sample:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var count = -1;

  function slideImg() {
    var imgs = $('.img');
    var imgLength = imgs.length - 1;
    
    imgs.css("z-index","").eq(count).css("z-index","2");
    count < imgLength ? count++ : count = 0;
    imgs.addClass('slide').eq(count).removeClass('slide');
  }

  setInterval(slideImg, 5000);

});
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide {
  right: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: 2s !important;
  transition: 2s !important;
}

.img.slide:first-child {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=10" />
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=23" />
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=4" />
</div>
```

---

**Solution 2:** *(Background image slides-out)*

Instead of having `slide` on all of your images and removing it from one, only apply the `slide` class to one image at any time:

```
imgs.removeClass('slide').eq(count).addClass('slide');
```

**Sample:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var count = -1;

  function slideImg() {
    var imgs = $('.img');
    var imgLength = imgs.length - 1;
    
    count < imgLength ? count++ : count = 0;
    imgs.removeClass('slide').eq(count).addClass('slide');

  }

  setInterval(slideImg, 5000);

});
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide {
  right: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: 2s !important;
  transition: 2s !important;
}

.img.slide:first-child {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=10" />
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=23" />
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Santi. I'll test this out

Answer (score 0):

Other answers and commenters are correct that you are applying `.slide` to all images. Here is another way to implement, that doesn't require having to deal with z-index.

Instead it selects the `.img` based on its index and then applies the addClass to just that image and removes the class using the `.eq()` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var count = 0;

  function slideImg() {
    var imgs = $('.img');
    var imgLength = imgs.length;

    count < imgLength ? count++ : count = 0;

    $(imgs[count - 1]).addClass('slide').eq(count).removeClass('slide');
  }

  setInterval(slideImg, 2000);
});
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide {
    right: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: 2s !important;
    transition: 2s !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-wrapper">
   <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=10" />
   <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=23" />
   <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=4" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var count = 0;
  
function slideImg() {
   var imgs = $('.img');

   var imgLength = imgs.length - 1;
   
   count < imgLength ? count++ : count = 0;
   imgs.removeClass('slide');
imgs.eq(count).addClass('slide');
}
  
setInterval(slideImg, 5000);

});
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide {
  right: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: 2s !important;
  transition: 2s !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=10" />
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=23" />
  <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=4" />
</div>
```

Comment: I believe it's because your answer provides no context. It neither explains what was wrong with OP's code, nor what you've changed to fix it. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Your answer is currently a game of spot-the-difference.